# Close View when .onDrag leaves view boundaries in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to close my object-menu as soon as my finger crosses the border of the view when dragging an item. CARE: I do not want to close the item when dropping the item. Unfortunately I have no idea on how to achieve this.

[image: Example]

I am simply using:

```
struct BuildingItemSlot: View {

    var preview: ObjectPreview
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(contentsOfFile: preview.dataPath + "/Raw/Thumbnails/" + preview.id + ".png") ?? UIImage())
                .resizable()
                //.scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 64, height: 64)
                .padding(4)
                //.border(Color.black, width: 1)
        }
        .onDrag({ NSItemProvider() })
    }
}
```

embedded in a view that makes up the inventory ...

```
VStack() {
     ForEach(networkManager.objectPreviewList.objects ?? []){ preview in 
             BuildingItemSlot(preview: preview)
          }
      }
      .padding(40)
```

I am opening and closing the side menu simply by with:

```
.offset(x: stateHandler.openBuildingsMenu ? 0 : 480)
```

Thanks a lot,
Jakob

Comment: You could use a `DropDelegate`, it has functions like `dropEntered`, `dropExited`, `dropUpdated`, `validateDrop` and `performDrop`. In your case `dropEntered` and `dropExited` could be used

Comment: Thank you very much! I looked into it and it seems the right way to do this. Do you know if there is any possibility to interrupt this gesture? So f.E. to stop the gesture (and deleting the preview) when you drag over a specific area?

Comment: DropDelegate doesn't have an option to interrupt drag gesture, however `validateDrop` would be called, so you can have your logic whether to say if the drop is valid or invalid. `onDrop(of:delegate)` is the view modifier to be used on the view which can accept a drop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Approach:

- Use `onDrop(of:delegate)` is the view modifier to be used on the view which can accept a drop.
- The DropDelegate has functions like

  - `dropEntered`,
  - `dropExited`,
  - `dropUpdated`,
  - `validateDrop` - You can dynamically validate if drop is valid or not
  - `performDrop`
- Play around with above functions by adding print statements

## Interruptions:

- It is not possible to interrupt drag gestures however `validateDrop` should give you control when to accept / deny drop dynamically.

## Reference:

#### Mac

- [SwiftUI on the Mac: The finishing touches](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10289)
- [Building a great mac app with SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/building_a_great_mac_app_with_swiftui)

#### iOS

- [Drag & Drop with SwiftUI](https://swiftui-lab.com/drag-drop-with-swiftui/)

## Note:

- There are some SwiftUI bugs for drag and drop for macOS and iOS, if you encounter any bugs drop a comment as it is difficult to list all the bugs.